# How can I convert a Map<String, List<Object>> to a List?

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I like to convert a map that contains a string and a list of object into a list.

```
Map<String, List<Object>>
```

How can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To a list of what?

Comment: A list of what? The values or the key?

Comment: Be more specific by providing pseudo examples

Comment: What are you expecting in List ?

Comment: Which result do yo want: `[key0, value0, key1, value1 ... keyN, valueN]` or `[key0, key1 ... keyN]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a list of all the objects in the map values this would be a way to do it:

```
List<Object> all = new LinkedList<>();
for (Collection<Object> l : map.values()) {
    all.addAll(l);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, List<Object>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<Object>>();

// Assuming map containing a key with "Apple"
// This is how you get the list indicated by key Apple
List<Object> myObjects = myMap.get("Apple");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert list of Object into your DTO List as follows.

```
ArrayList<DTOtoMAP> mylist = (ArrayList<DTOtoMAP>) (Object) hashMap.get(0);
```